# SqlBulkCopy Insert with Identity Column

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy, identity-insert

I am using the `SqlBulkCopy` object to insert a couple million generated rows into a database. The only problem is that the table I am inserting to has an identity column. I have tried setting the `SqlBulkCopyOptions` to `SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity` and setting the identity column to `0`'s, `DbNull.Value` and `null`. None of which have worked. I feel like I am missing something pretty simple, if someone could enlighten me that would be fantastic. Thanks!

*edit* To clarify, I do not have the identity values set in the `DataTable` I am importing. I want them to be generated as part of the import.

*edit 2*
    Here is the code I use to create the base `SqlBulkCopy` object.

```
SqlBulkCopy sbc = GetBulkCopy(SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity);
sbc.DestinationTableName = LOOKUP_TABLE;

private static SqlBulkCopy GetBulkCopy(SqlBulkCopyOptions options = 
    SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default) 
{
    Configuration cfg = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/RSWifi");
    string connString =
    cfg.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["WifiData"].ConnectionString;
    return new SqlBulkCopy(connString, options);
}
```

Comment: Now if only there was a ay to get the @@IDENTITY back in bulk to update the source..

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To have the destination table assign the identity, **DO NOT** use the `SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity` option. Instead, **don't** map the identity from the source, and **don't** extract it from source to send through to `SqlBulkCopy`.

Comment: I actually need the Identity values to be generated at the time of the insert, if that helps.

Comment: Oh, you want the destination to assign the value? That wasn't at all clear from your question. Don't use `SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity`! Turn that off, and don't include it in the mapping nor when you pull from `source`.

Comment: Oh, I was confused by the documentation `When not specified, identity values are assigned by the destination.` I thought it meant when a value wasn't specified :(

Comment: @FlyingStreudel: Exactly. There are a bunch of options in `SqlBulkCopyOptions`. When you do not specify the `SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity` option, the destination table will assign the identity.

Answer (score 33):

Fill the [`ColumnMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.columnmappings.aspx) of the `BulkCopy` object and don't map the identity column. The identity column will be generated by the target database.

Comment: This has just solved a problem which has plagued me for several hours.

Comment: This helped since my source/destination had different number of columns.  The source data had columns that were used for displaying data in a particular format.  That also meant duplicated data in the database.  So I used the ColumnMappings collection to skip certain columns in the source data that did not need to be saved in the database.

Comment: I didn't really understand this answer though I think it was the answer to my problem. If you don't add the identity column into the `DataTable`, e.g. `returnVal.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));` then you get a mapping problem. This column shouldn't be assigned a value though, so **don't** add `dataRow["id"] = ...etc.`

Answer (score 5):

You have two options -

1 - use `KeepIdentity` and preserve the source's `Identity` values.

2 - Don't map the `Identity` field.  If you don't try to assign a value the target table will assign one automatically.

Comment: Not assigning a variable is equivalent to assigning `DbNull.Value`. I still get the same `Column 'Id' does not allow DBNull.Value.` IOE :( Or did you mean don't even include the `Id` column in my `DataTable`?

Comment: @Flying - did you turn off `KeepIdentity`?  It needs to be `FALSE` for the target to assign a value.

Comment: I added the code I am using to create the `SqlBulkCopy` object. I dont see a field/property called `KeepIdentity` to set.

Comment: @Flying - apologies, don't set it to `TRUE`.  If it is set the destination will not auto-assign an identity

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it in .NET (`dt` is your data table):

```
dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ForEach((c, i) => sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(c.ColumnName, i + 1));
```

You basically skip the identity (`Id`) column by assigning your destination columns with an ordinal starting from 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 2):

This is the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductShippingMethodMap](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ShippingMethodId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParentProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductShippingMethodMap] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The bellow C# code is working

```
 DataTable dtQtyData = new DataTable();
        dtQtyData.Clear();
        dtQtyData.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));

    dtQtyData.Columns.Add("ProductId", typeof(int));
    dtQtyData.Columns.Add("ShippingMethodId", typeof(int));
    dtQtyData.Columns.Add("ParentProductId", typeof(int));


    for (int i = 0; i < ShippingMethodIds.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ProductIds.Length; j++)
        {
            var productId = ProductIds[j];
            var shippingMethodId = ShippingMethodIds[i];
            dtQtyData.Rows.Add(new object[] {0,productId, shippingMethodId, parentProductId });
        }

    }
    var connectionString = new DataSettingsManager().LoadSettings().DataConnectionString;
    SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default);
    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "ProductShippingMethodMap";
    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dtQtyData);
```

Comment: I keep getting primary key duplicate violation.

Comment: It should not be as at the table definition [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, is the primary key and autoincrement by 1. So it should abide by the rule.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You are right using  `SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity` option then bulkcopy writer doesn't think that what is you table structure this object write from start column, so for our need, I am doing in same way to preserve identity field in my table  just you have to make a extra column in you datatable object with rest of your needful columns and pass null values to this column then table automatically handles Identity.

Answer (score 0):

When using the JDBC SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord structures, the identity column DOES need to be mapped, but the value in the identity column is ignored.

Answer (score -1):

In my case it turned out to be blank space inside the column name and in one of the columns I had accidently used hyphon (-) instead of underscore (_) in my SQL table.
I replaced blank space and hyphon with underscore in the sql table and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score -2):

**Cause** :- There were some empty rows in the excel at the end of the data, which possibly looks like blank rows. Bulk upload was trying to upload these blank rows into the table.

**Solution** :- Select only the rows which contains data - copy the data into the new sheet. Say you have your data in 'Sheet 1', move it to 'Sheet 2' and delete 'Sheet 1'.