# Doing BULK Insert SUSPENDED With Wait Type LCK_M_RIn_LN

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, winforms, database

I'm having awful problems with doing BULK insert. I'm actually using SqlBulkCopy to insert a number of rows into a table. At first, I would get a Timeout exception. So, I set the SqlBulkCopy's BulkCopyTimeout to a ridiculous[?] 1800 seconds. The exception wouldn't be thrown (yet). So, I checked the Activity Monitor (as suggested here: [Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The statement has been terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602395/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation)) from the MS Server management studio and saw that my BULK INSERT's Task Status is SUSPENDED with a Wait Type of LCK_M_RIn_LN.My code goes like this:

```vb
Using sqlCon As SqlConnection = connection.Connect()
   Dim sqlBulkCopy As New SqlBulkCopy(sqlCon, SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints And
   SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers And
   SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls And
   SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, sqlTran)

   sqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 1800 ' is this ridiculous?
   sqlBulkCopy.BatchSize = 1000
   sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTable
   sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTableObject)

   sqlTran.Commit()
End Using
```

I have been searching for solutions in the web, but to no avail. Although I have found this defintion of LCK_M_RIn_LN:

> Occurs when a task is waiting to acquire a NULL lock on the current key value, and an Insert Range lock between the current and previous key. A NULL lock on the key is an instant release lock. For a lock compatibility matrix, see sys.dm_tran_locks (Transact-SQL).

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179984.aspx

But it's not helping. May someone help me out. My deepest gratitude.

***Edit***

I think it's because of the KeepIdentity attribute because the primary key is auto incremented. This is according to [SqlBulkCopy Insert with Identity Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651809/sqlbulkcopy-insert-with-identity-column). I'll see if it fixes my issue.

***Edit 2***

I don't know what's happening but BULK insert worked fine when I tested it on the management studio (using direct transact-sql). I don't know. Maybe it's with the SqlBulkCopy. When I checked on the Activity Monitor, the query it generated was this:

`insert bulk TableName ([ColumnName] Int)`

***Edit 3***

I forgot to write that I'm actually using Entity Framework so I copied a code (translated from c# to vb, actually) that would create a DataTable from an entity object since EntityDataReader is only available for C# (which distressed me). But, anyway. I trashed the SqlBulkCopy thing and just stored the values in XML because when I look at it, I realized I did not need the values inside a database.

Comment: What's the actual error message? Also, you can add the DBMS you're using as a tag to your question, that makes it easier for other users to help you.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks. At first, it threw a Timeout exception so I set the BulkCopyTimeout to 1800 seconds. But, then I found out from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602395/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation the possibilities so I checked my Activity Monitor in MS management studio and found out that the bulk insert was suspended. I have updated my question to include this details. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Phebe, thanks for the update. Last request: can you please also add the tag for the programming language you're using to your question?

Comment: Btw: feel free to answer your own question and accept it if it solves your problem! That might just help out a fellow programmer some day :-)

Comment: @PenguinBlues well, you didn't awser your own question... :P

Comment: Well I don't really have an answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I hit something similar trying to bulk insert from Java but with wait type `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` e.g.

```
+-----------+-------+-------------+---------+--------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
|  Status   | BlkBy |   Command   | CPUTime | DiskIO |   LastBatch    |             ProgramName              |
+-----------+-------+-------------+---------+--------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
| SUSPENDED | .     | BULK INSERT |      15 |      4 | 09/16 02:42:04 | Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server |
+-----------+-------+-------------+---------+--------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
```

It's hard to say what the exact issue was, there are a few things I observed:

- Either is the driver swallows errors or you only get them when the copy completes, e.g. when I tried to insert a single row I had exceptions thrown with the errors I needed to fix.
- Tuning can be important, specifically the batch size (see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165966/how-does-one-investigate-the-performance-of-a-bulk-insert-statement)

Once I'd addressed these then the full load worked as expected.

Some stats for batch size/rows I generated (note the data is going across the Atlantic) but the point is that the performance is very variable.

```
+------------+------+----------+----------+----------+
| batch size | rows |  start   |   end    | duration |
+------------+------+----------+----------+----------+
|        100 | 2500 | 09:15:45 | 09:18:17 | 00:02:32 |
|       1000 | 2500 | 09:23:34 | 09:25:35 | 00:02:00 |
|       2500 | 2500 | 09:32:53 | 09:34:55 | 00:02:01 |
|       2500 | 7500 | 10:27:18 | 10:30:49 | 00:03:31 |
|       7500 | 7500 | 10:38:10 | 10:45:57 | 00:07:47 |
+------------+------+----------+----------+----------+
```