# Adding Data To DataTable not knowing Primary Key Value

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, datatable

I've written a program in VB (although I'm equally comfortable with C#, so please answer in either language) that is used to insert a large amount of data into a table in my SQL server DB.

The way I've planned on doing it is:

1. To get the table's Schema from the DB using the `SqlDataAdapter.FillSchema` method.
2. Add the many rows of data to my DataTable
3. Use `SqlBulkCopy` (`.WriteToServer(dtToCopy.CreateDataReader)`) to load in the data

I've done this many times before and it's proven very efficient. My problem is that the table I'm writing to has an auto-incrementing primary key column, `RowNum`.

Now I know I could re-query my table after getting the schema and get the latest value of `RowNum` and simply write in the values myself into the corresponding column in my DataTable, but my fear is that the table may change between the time of my query and the time of my write, in which case, I could have un-desirable results.

I've seen posts relating to `MissingSchemaAction` > `AddWithKey`, but I'm not sure exactly how I could implement it in my case?

Would I just remove the primary key and delete the `RowNum` column from my DataTable? 
And, if so, at what point do I set that property? It doesn't seem to be a property of the DataTable and I don't see where to add it in the SqlBulkCopy.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Does your DataTable currently have that RowNum column, and if so, with a "default" value or with "usable" values?

Comment: @BernhardHiller, it gets the column from the Database with the `FillSchema` command, but it doesn't get the seed value...

Comment: Creating a data table for large amount of data is inefficient. Suppose you have 10 million records, you don't wanna load it all into memory. You may want to consider using a data reader instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/434atets(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, @Neolisk, I also have that procedure. For this specific example, though, I liked the DataTable since I also perform Linq queries against it and use it in my code elsewhere, but a very useful and logical suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: You can use Linq-To-Sql for that.

Comment: Makes sense... Gonna try and implement it... Thanks @Neolisk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I found the solution myself.

Basically, I had to:

1. Set the `PrimaryKey` property of my DataTable to `Nothing`
2. Remove the `RowNum` column from my DataTable
3. Use `ColumnMappings` for my `SqlBulkCopy` so every other column is mapped and the identity is left out

Then, since it is a primary key and set as auto-increment in the DB, it gets automatically assigned the correct values at the time of load.

Hope this helps others!!!

Main Source:
[SqlBulkCopy Insert with Identity Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651809/sqlbulkcopy-insert-with-identity-column)