# Error cannot insert null values in multiple primary key column :SQLBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy

I have a SQL Server table where the 1st column `ID` is primary identity column, 2nd column is `BatchId` which is also part of the primary key.

In datatable `dt`, I am adding column `batchId` explicitly. When inserting from the datatable to SQL Server using `SqlBulkCopy`, I am assigning same value to `batchId` column (for e.g. for today's date `batchId` will be `1`, for next date `batchId` will be `2` and so on), but `SqlBulkCopy` states error

> Cannot insert null values to column BatchId from table 'xxxx'";

despite assigning values. I have also passed the `SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity` & `SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls` parameters to `SqlBulkCopy` class.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: As far as I know, `SqlBulkCopy` will always try to insert values into all columns of the target table. So in your case, this won't work - since you don't want to provide a value for the `ID` identity column. Solution: you need to bulk-load your data into a **staging** table that has the exact same structure as your `DataTable`, and then do an insert from there into the actual, main table on SQL Server (specifying to omit the `ID` column in your `INSERT` statement)

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651809/sqlbulkcopy-insert-with-identity-column